# Can't start Jenkins in a Docker: Fails to bind 0.0.0.0:50000

Tags: docker, jenkins

I installed Docker on a Windows 10 Pro system and grabbed the jenkins/jenkins:lts package to test out Jenkins stuff.  It worked for a few days but then stopped launching because it's getting a permission denied error when trying to bind a port.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the jenkins image in docker and uninstall/reinstall docker but nothing works now. It won't ever launch for me.

Here's what I use to run the image:

```
docker run --name=jenkins --hostname=jenkins -p 50000:50000 -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Here's the error I get:

```
docker run --name=jenkins --hostname=jenkins -p 50000:50000 -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jenkins (6615f4f62278459ed33a370bb7bf978e176e2831a7736d4a98d79181bb084c70): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:50000: unexpected error Permission denied.
```

I'm going by what I'm seeing on the readme at the jenkins docker page:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

I'm not that great at troubleshooting things like this in Windows, but I did some basic stuff looking at the ports in use, etc. I don't see anything jumping out at me that looks like it's already in use.

I've also tried running this in an administrator command shell too but it's always denied.

I have deleted everything in my appdata too related to docker that I could find when I've tried this but it still won't work.

Any ideas on now to get this sorted out would be great.  Any commands to force an unbind or how to -fully- remove docker since uninstalls never actually remove everything :/ would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I think is related to this issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1804 and this issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3103. You get help from there.

Comment: you may use `netstat -nlptu` to see whether it's in use or not.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll dig in and see if I can un-stick it tonight.